# Using RabbitMQ or any message broker to communicate OPC client and microservie controller

Tags: python, c#, rabbitmq, microservices, opc

We having the following scenario of a system that has OPC server and we building OPC client to interface to it and on the other side we have a microserver (Controller) that we want to communicate with the OPC client to control the system. What is the best way to have the microservice controller to communicate with the OPC client? is RabbitMQ or any other broker an option?

a very high level diagram of what I am trying to accomplish is in below pic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want the microservice controller to "**communicate**" with the OPC Client, what does that mean?

You see, if you have an OPC Client, that gives you the ability to:

- Subscribe to tags in an OPC Server and get data changes.
- Read a specific values from 1 tag or more in an OPC Server.
- Write a specific value to 1 tag or more in an OPC Server.

Usually, you would put all your business logic in the OPC Client and be done with it.  But if you are adding a microservice into the mix, then your OPC Client becomes another proxy.  Remember the OPC Server is already the proxy for the actual devices on the network.

So do you want the microservice to:

- Recieve updates for all data changes?
- Or do you want the ability to 'write to' and 'read from' specific tags in microservice?
- Or both!

**Pushing data updates to microservice**

If you just want the microservice to recieve "data updates" for all changes to the subscribed tags then Rabbit MQ is a great fit.  Its fast and scalable. If the microservice goes down, then the messages are preserved until it comes back up so you dont lose any data. Rabbit MQ is robust and reliable.

To push messages onto the queue, you will need to update the code of your OPC Client to send messages to a RabbitMQ queue.  You can do this either via the offical c# nuget packages or you can even add messages to  a queue using a simple HTTP posts (so you could use the C# `HttpClient` class to send messages).

**Reading / Writing data for specific tags from microservice**

If you want to read and write to specific tags from the microservice, then thats different.  Notice above for "data updates" the OPC Client just had to push out to a rabbit queue regardless of if anything was listening or not.

But, if you want to be able to read or write to a specific tag from the microservice then you will need something like a web interface (or maybe shared database table)
that the OPC Client can monitor.  That way, the microservice could call the web interface to write a specific value down to a tag or read from a specific tag and get the result.